# Crear gráfico en forma de malla desde java

Tags: java, excel, matlab

he escrito en java un simulador de trenes y necesito exportar los datos almacenados a un gráfico de malla como el del siguiente ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los datos están organizados del siguiente modo:

- cada tren es un objeto
- cada objeto tren tiene 2 arraylist
- el primer arraylist tiene las paradas, que son 25 pero se repiten durante   el recorrido ya que es circular
- el segundo arraylist tiene los tiempos de cada parada, almacenados de forma correlativa

No he encontrado nada sobre como hacer este gráfico desde java y me planteo si sería preferible exportar los datos a un archivo excel por ejemplo, y desde ahí tratar de generar la gráfica. Si exporto los datos de cada tren (en total 16) a una hoja de excel cada uno, ¿como podría unir luego estos datos en la gráfica? Tengo algunas nociones de matlab, pero no veo como podría exportar los datos de los 16 trenes para pasarlos a la gráfica.

Espero que puedan orientarme.

Answer (score 0):

Para utilizar matlab desde Java deberás de agregar al classpath la librería `javabuilder.jar`, esta librería la puedes hallar en

> matlabroot\toolbox\javabuilder\jar\javabuilder.jar

donde `matlabroot` es la carpeta de instalación de tu matlab.

Eso te habilitará los imports del paquete `com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.*`.

ahora a tu código en matlab deberás de pasarlo a un jar mediante la invocación desde matlab del javabuilder.jar en loq ue se conoce como `Library Compiler`.

Para abrir tu compilador de librerías de matlab debes introducir en el prompt el comando

> libraryCompiler

una vez abierto el dialogo deberás de seleccionar la opción `Java package` y especificar los archivos `.m`.

Para este ejemplo digamos que tu archivo contiene lo siguiente:

```
function drawplot(x,y)
plot(x,y);
```

y que como nombre de tu jar en el asistente eliges "plotdemo", esto automáticamente creará el archivo plotdemo.jar con un paquete por defecto llamado plotdemo, así que deberemos de importarlo en nuestro programa Java mediante

> import plotdemo.*;

Ahora desde Java deberíamos de poder llamar a la función de la siguiente manera

```
/* Necessary package imports */
import com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.*;
import plotdemo.*;

/*
 * createplot class demonstrates plotting x-y data into 
 * a MATLAB figure window by graphing a simple parabola.
 */
class createplot
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      MWNumericArray x = null;   /* Array of x values */
      MWNumericArray y = null;   /* Array of y values */
      plotter thePlot = null;    /* Plotter class instance */
      int n = 20;                /* Number of points to plot */

      try
      {
         /* Allocate arrays for x and y values */
         int[] dims = {1, n};
         x = MWNumericArray.newInstance(dims, 
            MWClassID.DOUBLE, MWComplexity.REAL);
         y = MWNumericArray.newInstance(dims, 
            MWClassID.DOUBLE, MWComplexity.REAL);

         /* Set values so that y = x^2 */
         for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
         {
            x.set(i, i);
            y.set(i, i*i);
         }

         /* Create new plotter object */
         thePlot = new plotter();

         /* Plot data */
         thePlot.drawplot(x, y);
         thePlot.waitForFigures(); 
      }

      catch (Exception e)
      {
         System.out.println("Exception: " + e.toString());
      }

      finally
      {
         /* Free native resources */
         MWArray.disposeArray(x);
         MWArray.disposeArray(y);
         if (thePlot != null)
            thePlot.dispose();
      }
   }
```

agregas a tu classpath los dos jars generados para poder compilar, si solo puedes hacerlo a manita desde línea de comandos puedes usar el comando:

- windows

  > javac -classpath
  >   .;matlabroot\toolbox\javabuilder\jar\javabuilder.jar;
  >   .\distrib\plotdemo.jar createplot.java
- linux

  > javac -classpath
  >   .:matlabroot/toolbox/javabuilder/jar/javabuilder.jar:
  >   ./distrib/plotdemo.jar createplot.java

Para ejecutar tu código lo corres normalmente, es decir:

- Windows

  > java -classpath
  >   .;matlabroot\toolbox\javabuilder\jar\javabuilder.jar;
  >   .\distrib\plotdemo.jar 
  >   createplot
- Linux

  > java -classpath
  >   .:matlabroot/toolbox/javabuilder/jar/javabuilder.jar:
  >   ./distrib/plotdemo.jar 
  >   createplot

El resultado debería de ser una ventana como las de matlab mostrando tu gráfica.

Toda esta información la he traducido de las fuentes oficiales y te dejo los hiperenlaces en caso de que los requieras:

- [Creación de un paquete de Java usando Matlab](https://la.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/gs/create-a-java-application-with-matlab-code.html)
- [Mostrar una gráfica de Matlab en un programa Java](https://la.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/java/plot-example.html)

Comment: Este proyecto ya se terminó hace 1 año y en este momento tampoco tengo posibilidad de probar tu código por falta de tiempo. Pero igualmente muchas gracias. Quizá en otro momento pueda ser de ayuda.

Comment: @Ch3ssMaster sería buena idea agregar una respuesta comentando como resolviste el problema, sería muy valioso para la comunidad, saludos.